# how to perform similarity function over columns of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cosine-similarity

I have a tensor like this:

```
tf_a1 =      [[-0.65 0.   0.   0.   0.42  0.   0.   0.51 0.   0.34 0.]
              [0.   -0.51 0.   0.  -0.52  0.   0.   0.   0.53 0.42 0.]
              [0.    0.32 0.  -0.50 0.34  0.   0.   0.39 0.32 0.52 0.]
              [0.    0.23 0.37 0.   0.    0.37 0.37 0.   0.47 0.39 0.3 ]]
```

I want to apply `cosine similarity` over each column of this tensor. So, I want to find the similarity of the first column versus rest of the columns. Again, second column against rest of the columns and so on.

I have done this using the for loop as such:

```
def cosine_score(x):
    for i, arr in enumerate(x):
        if i == 0 :
            first = cosine_similarity(x[i,].reshape(1, -1), x)
        else:
            second = cosine_similarity(x[i,].reshape(1, -1), x)
            final = tf.concat((first, second), axis=0)
            first = final
    return final
sim_topics = cosine_score(tf_a1)
```

Now, When I want to include this in my model, I can not use foor loop as it is. seems I have to use  `tf.map_fn` to go over it.

I also have done like this:

```
def cosine_score(x):
    def cos_similarity(col):
        for i, arr in enumerate(col):
            if i == 0:
                first = cosine_similarity(col[i, ].reshape(1, -1), col)
            else:
                second = cosine_similarity(col[i, ].reshape(1, -1), col)
                final = tf.concat((first, second), axis=0)
                first = final
        return final
    sim = tf.map_fn(cos_similarity, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return sim
```

But here I need to remove the `for loop`. My problem is that if I remove `for loop` and access each column seperately, how can I access the rest of the columns to compare and apply `cosine similarity`.

Please let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosine similarity is nothing more than an L2 normalized dot product. So, in `Tensorflow` this should do the trick for you:

```
# Normalize the columns of the tensor
normalized_tensor = tf.math.l2_normalize(tf_a1, axis=0)
# Get the dot product between the columns
scores = tf.matmul(normalized_tensor, normalized_tensor, transpose_a=True)
```

The tensor `scores` contains the cosine similarity between the columns of `tf_a1`. Moreover, below is a `Numpy` equivalent implementation:

```
# Normalize the columns of the tensor
normalized_tensor = tf_a1 / np.linalg.norm(tf_a1, axis=0)
# Get the dot product between the columns
scores = np.dot(normalized_tensor.T, normalized_tensor)
```

Finally, if you want to keep only one of the triangles (for example the upper triangle), and set the main diagonal to `0`, you can do the following in `Tensorflow`:

```
zero_diag = tf.linalg.set_diag(scores, tf.zeros(tf.shape(scores)[0]))
triangular = tf.matrix_band_part(zero_diag, 0, -1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will try this on the model and get back to you

Comment: I also included a `numpy` equivalent implementation for reference. Let me know of the outcome.

Comment: So should not the result tensor be a 1*11 tensor based on the tensor I have? it giving me 11*11 tensor shape. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You get a 11*11 diagonal matrix. The main diagonal consists of `1` because it represents the similarity between each of the columns and themselves. Also, the matrix is symmetrical, meaning that the top of bottom triangle are the same. Do you get my point?

Comment: Moreover, even if you want a flat tensor, it shouldn't be 1 * 11. You have 11 columns, so the similarity of the first column and the rest+itself is 11 elements, the second and the rest is 11 elements...Which is exactly what the matrix represents.

Comment: Totally, I missed it is symmetrical, my bad.

Comment: Excellent. I added an additional part in my answer where I set the main diagonal to `0` and I just take the upper triangle (In case you need something like this).

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it.

Comment: if I have normalized the data before feeding to the model, do you think I need to normalize it again? so `Z= W*x + b` , `x` has been normalized before then Im going to apply `cos_sim` on the `Z`.

Comment: Usually, if you are learning a metric (dot product, cosine similarity) it doesn't really matter. You will be fine just doing a dot product (not normalizing after `W*x + b`)